# wsgi.py fails with "No module named 'django'" in virtualenv on apache

Tags: python, django, apache, virtualenv, mod-wsgi

I am running a Django webapp on an Amazon Linux EC2 server and have properly installed and verified Apache and mod_wsgi. I configured the Apache config file as shown below and verified that the proper paths are loaded in Python by printing `sys.path` (shown in error log), however, I keep getting a 500 error with the `wsgi.py` file failing with a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'` error. I get the same error when using daemon mode in the apache config file. What am I missing?

My virtualenv is at `/var/www/html/test` and my webapp is at `/var/www/html/ai_demo_webapp/webapp` (this is the location of my `manage.py` file). I am using Apache 2.2.34 with the pip version of mod_wsgi, and have loaded the wsgi module in the apache config file as `LoadModule wsgi_module "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py36.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so"`.

**wsgi.py**

```
import os
import sys

print(sys.path)

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "webapp.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

**Apache Config File**

```
WSGIPythonHome /var/www/html/test
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/html/ai_demo_webapp/webapp

<VirtualHost *:80>
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/ai_demo_webapp/webapp/webapp/wsgi.py

<Directory /var/www/html/ai_demo_webapp/webapp/webapp>
<Files wsgi.py>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**Apache Error Log when apache is restarted and site is accessed**

```
[Mon Jun 11 05:01:46 2018] [notice] SIGHUP received.  Attempting to restart
[Mon Jun 11 05:01:46 2018] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Mon Jun 11 05:01:46 2018] [notice] Digest: done
[Mon Jun 11 05:01:46 2018] [notice] Apache/2.2.34 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_wsgi/4.6.4 Python/3.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jun 11 05:01:50 2018] [error] ['/var/www/html/ai_demo_webapp/webapp', '/var/www/html/test/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages', '/var/www/html/test/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/var/www/html/test/lib64/python3.6', '/var/www/html/test/lib/python3.6', '/var/www/html/test/lib64/python3.6/site-packages', '/var/www/html/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/var/www/html/test/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/lib64/python3.6', '/usr/lib/python3.6', '/usr/lib64/python3.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload']
[Mon Jun 11 05:01:50 2018] [error] [client 75.82.153.200] mod_wsgi (pid=27915): Failed to exec Python script file '/var/www/html/ai_demo_webapp/webapp/webapp/wsgi.py'.
[Mon Jun 11 05:01:50 2018] [error] [client 75.82.153.200] mod_wsgi (pid=27915): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/html/ai_demo_webapp/webapp/webapp/wsgi.py'.
[Mon Jun 11 05:01:50 2018] [error] [client 75.82.153.200] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon Jun 11 05:01:50 2018] [error] [client 75.82.153.200]   File "/var/www/html/ai_demo_webapp/webapp/webapp/wsgi.py", line 27, in <module>
[Mon Jun 11 05:01:50 2018] [error] [client 75.82.153.200]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Mon Jun 11 05:01:50 2018] [error] [client 75.82.153.200] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
[Mon Jun 11 05:01:51 2018] [error] ['/var/www/html/ai_demo_webapp/webapp', '/var/www/html/test/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages', '/var/www/html/test/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/var/www/html/test/lib64/python3.6', '/var/www/html/test/lib/python3.6', '/var/www/html/test/lib64/python3.6/site-packages', '/var/www/html/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/var/www/html/test/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/lib64/python3.6', '/usr/lib/python3.6', '/usr/lib64/python3.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload']
[Mon Jun 11 05:01:51 2018] [error] [client 75.82.153.200] mod_wsgi (pid=27919): Failed to exec Python script file '/var/www/html/ai_demo_webapp/webapp/webapp/wsgi.py'., referer: http://ec2-54-149-122-177.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/
[Mon Jun 11 05:01:51 2018] [error] [client 75.82.153.200] mod_wsgi (pid=27919): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/html/ai_demo_webapp/webapp/webapp/wsgi.py'., referer: http://ec2-54-149-122-177.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/
[Mon Jun 11 05:01:51 2018] [error] [client 75.82.153.200] Traceback (most recent call last):, referer: http://ec2-54-149-122-177.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/
[Mon Jun 11 05:01:51 2018] [error] [client 75.82.153.200]   File "/var/www/html/ai_demo_webapp/webapp/webapp/wsgi.py", line 27, in <module>, referer: http://ec2-54-149-122-177.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/
[Mon Jun 11 05:01:51 2018] [error] [client 75.82.153.200]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application, referer: http://ec2-54-149-122-177.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/
[Mon Jun 11 05:01:51 2018] [error] [client 75.82.153.200] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django', referer: http://ec2-54-149-122-177.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/
```

Comment: Is ``/var/www/html/test`` the value given by ``sys.prefix`` for the Python installation or virtual environment you want used? See http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html

Comment: You are also better off using daemon mode of mod_wsgi if you have sufficient control over the Apache setup.

Comment: Docker is another solution.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton yes, printing `sys.prefix` yields `/var/www/html/test` in the apache error log. This is the root directory of the virtual environment I am using and I have checked that the import statement works fine in a python shell on the server (within the virtual environment).

Comment: Are all the directories from ``/var/www`` right down to the ``site-packages`` and the ``django`` package directory in it, accessible to the user that Apache runs as?

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton the `django` package directory is inherited from `/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django` and Apache does run as `ec2-user`, so it should have permission and access to it, correct?

Comment: When you use a virtual environment, packages in the local per user Python area are not used. You will need to install it in the virtual environment.

Comment: Thank you @GrahamDumpleton, that did the trick. If you add it as answer I'll accept it.